# How To Unit Test A Public Method That Modifies The State Of Private Member Fields?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I am trying to unit test the following method for a class that implements [IHostedService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostedservice?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) interface.

```
public async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        _cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
        _pollLoopThread.Join();
    });
}
```

Currently, the `CancellationTokenSource` and `Thread` fields are private.

In such circumstances how could I unit test this method?

1. Refactor the class so that the thread and cancellation token are injected constructor dependencies, which can subsequently be mocked.
2. Add a property `IsRunning` to allow testing feature that the hosted service is started or stopped
3. Do not unit test the `StopAsync` method

Comment: If the method has no effect whatsoever on anything observable by public properties/methods, don't test it.

Comment: Ok, thanks....yep currently method has no observable effect